# How to convert each array within a 2D array into a string in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

Im trying to convert each element within a 2D array into a string. So for example i would like to convert something like this [ [ 'ICjs', 'phCL' ] [ 'ksRp', 'nyhk' ] [ '4956', 'UiFS' ] ] into something like this ['ICjs - phCL', 'ksRp - nyhk', '4956- UiFS']

I have already tried to convert each array within a 2D array to string and then replace ',' with ' - '. I'm getting cannot read property 'toString' of undefined.

```
const arr1 = [ [ 'ICjs', 'phCL' ] [ 'ksRp', 'nyhk' ] [ '4956', 'UiFS' ] ];
const arr2 = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  const text = await arr[i].toString();
  await text.replace(/,/g, " - ");
  await arr2.push(text);
}
return arr2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping each inner array to its [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ed form.

```js
const arr2 = arr1.map(arr => arr.join(" - "));
```

The bug in your question is because you are iterating from index `0` to index `arr.length`, however, an array of length `arr.length` only has indices from `0` to `arr.length - 1`. So, on the last iteration of your loop, you are accessing a non-existent index, which returns `undefined`, and then you call `toString()` on that non-existent element.

Note that ECMAScript has several powerful iteration constructs built into its standard library. As a general rule, you can say, when you are writing a loop, you are doing something wrong. There should be almost no need to write loops in TypeScript.